# Using a filter with a selection measure returning empty table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to filter a table as follows:

```
Table = Filter(Cashflows, Cashflows[Basis] = Cashflows[Basis Selection 1])
```

My selection measure is as follows:

```
Basis Selection 1 = SELECTEDVALUE('Basis CF1'[Value])
```

Basis CF1 is a slicer I have created from a table. My issue is that the filter returns only an empty table.

Thanks

Comment: You can't return a table like this. This works only when the table is a virtual and it's a part of measure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you cannot calculate tables dynamically at query time that are persisted to the data model. Calculated tables and calculated columns are calculated exactly once, which is at (data set) refresh time.

I suspect that at refresh time there is no valid `SELECTEDVALUE` for `'Basis CF1'[Value]`. This makes the function return a `BLANK()` (since you have not used the optional second argument), and your `FILTER` function filters the `Cashflows` table on rows where `Cashflow[Basis]` is blank. Perhaps there are no such rows, leading to a blank table being returned.